# OPENCV, can't open class VideoWriter

Tags: video, ubuntu, opencv

I'm newbie starting to use OpenCV on ubuntu 10.4. I'm trying to capture video from camera and to write that video on an avi file, the code is the next:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    namedWindow("cam1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Mat frame;

    VideoWriter outputVideo("lalala.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X') , 30, Size(720, 480) , true); // or frame.size()
    outputVideo.open("lalala.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X') ,  30, Size(720, 480), true) ;    // or frame.size()  

    if( !outputVideo.isOpened() ) {
      printf("VideoWriter failed to open!\n"); 
    }

    for(;;)
    {       
      cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera                        

      imshow("cam1", frame);

      outputVideo.write(frame); // or outputVideo << frame;

      if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I can't open the class VideoWriter but I get the frame well from the camera. I have tried with differents values of codecs and sizes but nothing changes.

Any idea of why the program don't initialize the class VideoWriter?

Comment: You are doind the same thing twice, `VideoWriter outputVideo(...)` and `outputVideo.open(...)`. =[ And try with codec **MJPG**, I don't know if OpenCV supports DIVX.

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't have permission to write the file, or you are using a codec that isn't included in your build of openCV.

To download and install the full opencv (including ffmpeg) see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20%3A%20Debian